# Where to define macros in DOS MASM assembly?

Tags: assembly, macros, masm

I need to know where to define macros in assembly code? I searched some websites but they don't used the structure of what our teacher told us!
the code structure is like below:

```
stk segment stack 'stack'
    dw 32 dup(?)
stk ends

dts segment
    msg db 'hello world$'
dts ends

cds segment
    assume cs:cds, ss:stk, ds:dts
main proc far

main endp
cds ends
end main
```

So my question is where is the best location to define macros? should we define it in code segment or before data segment?

Comment: Doesn't matter as macros are things for the assembler, they do not go into the output segments. I would put them at the top outside of segments.

Comment: @Jester Thanks for your answer. but if we had multiple procs in a .asm file & some of the macros are for a specific proc, it would maybe a mess. wouldn't?

Comment: Yeah if the macros are for a specific function, it may make sense to put them near. Matter of preference, the assembler doesn't care (as long as it's before the usage, normally).

Comment: @Jester Got it <3